# Accessing to mm1 register parts

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, mmx

Is it possible to access to a single byte in a mmx register, like a array?
I've this code:

```
movq mm1,vector1
movq mm2,vector2
psubw mm1,mm2
```

I want to put mm1[1],mm1[2],mm1[3]....into c++ vars, like:

```
int a,b=0;
mov a,mm1[1]
mov b,mm1[2]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I can show the code for SSE2 for c++, but is similar for MMX :

```
__m128i a;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) &a;
// access bytes pointed by pointer p
```

Comment: The compiler would have to copy entire register to stack, then do a bit of pointer arithmetic to calculate the address and just then it'll extract the byte. So this solution isn't that usable.

Comment: @buratinas Not if the registers are already on the stack. btw only way to confirm that is to check the compiler's output. Did you do it?

Comment: I am certain because there's no instruction to do that. Also, doing *any* calculations when data is on the stack is going to hurt a lot. If such an overhead can be accepted, what's the purpose of using SIMD then?

Comment: @buratinas SIMD instructions are usually used in a loop. If you use anything other then SIMD instructions, you will get huge performance hit. However, I am not aware that a register can't be on the stack. Can you provide a link explaining why is it bad?

Comment: I was talking not about registers on the stack but about extracting bytes out of MMX registers. No instructions can do that. So if we have data in MMX register and want to extract bytes, we must copy that register to the stack and do pointer arithmetics and so on, hence SIMD is not usable. It is usable when there is bunch of data in several arrays (needing only primitive addressing), the data can be copied using whole register stores/loads and processed using instructions involving whole extended registers.

Answer (score 6):

There's no direct possibility to address bytes in MMX registers unless you want to use `VJo`'s approach, but that completely undermines the benefits of using MMX in the first place.

However if you have the data in favorable format it's might possible to place them all in the registers and do a bunch of unpack operations, which would transpose the data.

BTW why don't you use SSE1/2/3/4? MMX is fairly obsolete. IIRC SSE4 has direct 8/16/32/64-bit extraction instructions.

Comment: I need to demostrate the benefits of using MMX. And I need to operate with two arrays and them extract this positions to fill objects.

But,is there any other possibility to do it?

Comment: Why can't you demonstrate the benefits of SSE2, for example, which every CPU that's less than 6 years old supports, and which is far more powerful

Comment: +1 for "MMX is fairly obsolete", but ditch the "fairly".  There is **no reason** to code for MMX today.  Use SSE.

Comment: @Stephon - We can't say that without knowing more about the situation of the person in question.  There are still some MMX (non-SSE) units still floating around in production use.  Upgrading may not be an option.  Nevermind that some emulators may not have support past that point too.  MMX may be the only choice.

Comment: @Brian: yes, there are still legacy systems that do not support SSE.  However, I would be very surprised if there are any in use in performance-critical environments where engineering work is ongoing.  Compare the cost of buying *the absolute cheapest x86 system available today* (which will support SSE, and be orders of magnitude faster than any legacy system that does not) to the cost of paying a skilled engineer to hand-tune MMX code.  It's a no-brainer.